# python statsmodels logit.fit(), fitting issues

Tags: python, statsmodels

I only have a really basic understanding of the problem. For my data I simply want to fit a curve by logistic regression (y is binary 0/1, and x is from -5 to +5). When I use `statsmodels`, I get nice results and a wonderful summary.

```
 logit = statsmodels.api.Logit(z['HIT'],z[Indicator])  
 result = logit.fit()  
 ax.plot(np.sort(z[train_cols])*(-1),result.predict()[np.argsort(z[train_cols])],c = 'red', linewidth =2)
```

My problem is that the S-curve / fit is not shifted or compressed at all (sorry I do not know the right terminology). It is always forced to go through (0.5,0), which should not be the case, because that messes up the results.  If anyone could help me with this, that would be great.

Comment: Are you intentionally not including a constant? If you include a constant additional to your `x`, then the probability will not be 0.5 when x is zero.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply. Looks way better now :)